# how to read a large text file in a data frame from a .txt file in python

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I have a large text file which has names and long paragraphs of statements made by several different people. the file format is .txt, I am trying to separate the name and the statement into two different columns of a data frame.

Data is in this format-

```
Harvey: I’m inclined to give you a shot. But what if I decide to go the other way?

Mike: I’d say that’s fair. Sometimes I like to hang out with people who aren’t that bright, you know, just to see how the other half lives.
Mike in the club
(mike speaking to jessica.)
Jessica: How are you mike?

Mike: good!
.....
....
```

and so on

the length of text file is 4million.

in the output I need a dataframe with one name column having the name of speaker and another statement column with that persons respective statement.

Comment: What did you tried sofar? This problem could easily be solved with regular expressions if the text follows the strict pattern as shown in the example.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if: the format is always "name: one-liner-no-colon"
you could try:
`df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt',sep=': ', header=None)`

or go manually:

```
f = open("untitled.txt", "r")
file_contents = []

current_name = ""
current_dialogue = ""

for line in f:
    splitted_line = line.split(": ")
    if len(splitted_line) > 1:
        # you are on a row with name: on it
        # first stop the current dialogue - save it
        if current_name:
            file_contents.append([current_name, current_dialogue])
        # then update the name encountered
        current_name = splitted_line.pop(0)
        current_dialogue = ""
    current_dialogue += ": ".join(splitted_line)    
# add the last dialogue line
file_contents.append([current_name, current_dialogue])

f.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(file_contents)
df
```

Comment: Hey its not just a one liner, the dialogues me be of 5-10 lines or more.

Comment: could you give an example in your initial question where one name has associated 2 lines of dialogue and the "name:" appears only once, at the first line?

Comment: Added some manual parsing for you. Watch out, since the dialogue will contain also the side notes "...just to see how the other half lives.\nMike in the club\n(mike speaking to jessica.)\n"

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file line-by-line, you can use something like this to split the speaker from the spoken text, without using regex.

```
def find_speaker_and_text_from_line(line):
  split = line.split(": ")
  name = split.pop(0)
  rest = ": ".join(split)
  return name, rest
```

Comment: how to bring it in a data frame? I am a beginner don't really know much. Also before the start of dialogues there is name of the plot in brackets and a title above it how to handle that? we can delete or ignore that anyway?

Comment: These sort of "script" markups often have an actual filetype that you can convert them to before processing, such as `.fountain`. Do you have any way of transforming that file with some sort of converter to a more easily manipulated filetype?

Comment: No as of now i don't.